# "Позволять" vs "разрешать"

Tags: семантика, синонимы

Есть ли на **ваш взгляд** разница? Именно живая, не книжно-словарная разница.

Я ставлю вопрос именно так, в общем и целом. 
Контекст, если без него вопрос непонятен, там очень простой.

> - Позвольте вам не поверить!
> - Выучите уж наконец, начальник не позволяет, начальник разрешает.

Но тут важнее скорее не "текстовый" контекст, а ситуационный, если так можно сказать. Диалог произошел на форуме, где народу много самого разного, много тех, кому русский - не родной, а за словом в карман там не полезут.

Так вот шутку эту "военную" поняли лучше всего те, от кого меньше всего это можно было ожидать - братья-славяне (там болгар много, македонец есть, ну прежде всего украинцы украиноязычные, общаемся на двух языках). 
Вот я и задумался, а может я сам не понял, чего сказал с точки зрения носителя русского?!

(+)Болгары меня совсем с панталыку сбили.)))
https://translate.google.ru/#ru/bg/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C
Кто бы мог подумать.

(++)

> Для этого случая хотелось бы услышать более широкий контекст.

Да нету его. О том и речь. Один из собеседников (я) пересказал кое-что из слов своих проверенных знакомых - на горячую, как можно догадаться, тему. И в ответ другой собеседник без всякого обоснования или аргументации по сути обвинил первого во вранье (не будем искать мягкую формулировку). Ни о каких начальниках там речь не шла. Ну я и намекнул на наличие "неуставных отношений" в таком подходе моего оппонента. Ну не вписывается в рамки форумного этикета подобное, это просто хамство вопиющее. Как не вписывается в рамки устава это "позвольте" вместо "разрешите". Ну какой тут еще контекст нужен?!

Я не претендую на то, что у меня безошибочное ЧЮ, но тут реакция окружения меня просто поразила. Я не жаловаться сюда пришел, правда подозреваю, что меня поняли совсем не так, как я того желал.

И вообще вопрос я поставил абстрактно, безотносительно к контексту.

Answer (score 2):

Если всё-таки посмотреть в словарь, то из примеров видно, что официальные власти всё **только разрешают, а не позволяют**: Разрешают проведение симпозиума; посещение больных. Разрешают взлёт, посадку, приземление. Официальное обращение: разрешите начать испытание.

**Стилевая характеристика и область применения у этих слов, как мне кажется, разная.**

Глагол ***позволить*** ― менее официальный, его семантика примерно такая: дайте ваше согласие, чтобы я проявил **свое желание/волю** что-либо сделать.

Этот глагол может в некоторых ситуациях даже выражать **иронию и насмешку** по отношению к лицу, у которого будто бы спрашивают позволения.

Такая "репутация" глагола ***позволить*** препятствует его использованию в официальных ситуациях. Поэтому начальник всегда именно **разрешает** какие-либо действия, а **не позволяет** (то есть не согласовывает свою волю  с предложением подчиненных).

Comment: Ну в общем да. Это примерно то, что я ожидал услышать (детали я позже уточню), но вы понимаете, мне не очень нравится ваша отсылка к словарям... Яне ставил вопрос,как ***правильно** понимать эти слова, а именно как реально воспринимается в сознании носителя. Вот про "репутацию" - это пойдет. Это именно то, что ни в одном словаре не описано. И близко моему пониманию. Короче, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Мой взгляд: позволить = не препятствовать, разрешить (или дозволить) = дать предварительное согласие.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо. Тут действительно есть в чем покопаться. Хотя я, конечно, не так это все понимаю... "Дозволить" я понимал как несколько устаревший, но полный синоним "позволить". А вот разрешить - это уже несколько другое... Как активное разрешение, модно сказать официальное.

Comment: "Дозволить" я уверенно отношу к стороне "разрешить": и то, и другое _всегда_ имеет вербальное выражение и формально может быть напр. "высочайшим". Нельзя напр. никогда "дозволить умереть (не оказав помощи)", "дозволить бежать/скрыться" вместо "позволить".  "Разрешение" чаще имеет разовый характер, чем подустаревшее "дозволение", которое может быть предусмотрительно сформулировано списком и т. п.

Answer (score 1):

> Позвольте вам не поверить!

Здесь ни о каком позволении или разрешении речь не идёт. Это общепринятая более мягкая форма выражения "я вам не верю!". Поэтому здесь "позвольте" и "разрешите" в полной мере являются синонимами.

> Выучите уж наконец, начальник не позволяет, начальник разрешает.

Для этого случая хотелось бы услышать более широкий контекст. Оба синонима могут указывать на различие в статусах участников диалога, и это различие может отражаться по-разному на самом диалоге. Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию.

Начальник: "Кто выполнит эту задачу?"
Подчинённый: "Позвольте/разрешите мне".

Здесь нет принципиальной разницы между употреблением синонимов и рассматриваемый ответ начальника выглядел бы просто нелепо. Более того, слово "позвольте" здесь скорее подчёркивает признание подчинённым своего более низкого статуса.

Другой вариант: (подчинённый) "Позвольте мне высказать свою точку зрения." — (начальник) "Выучите уж наконец, начальник не позволяет, начальник разрешает".

Здесь видим желание осадить подчинённого, используя каламбур. С точки зрения начальника, в данной ситуации подчинённый должен был попросить: "разрешите мне высказать своё мнение?", а не констатировать факт: "я выскажу своё мнение". Я думаю, что контекст подразумевался примерно таким, и в этом случае "позволить" и "разрешить" также являются синонимами.

Я согласен, что в других случаях употребление этих слов может различаться, но не думаю, что есть различие в предложенных ситуациях.

Comment: Я в текст вопроса свой комментарий перенес.

Comment: @Мимоходов Каюсь, я действительно неправильно понял ситуацию. Ну тогда вообще всё вписывается в очерченные мной схемы: один человек ведёт себя непозволительно с точки зрения другого, другой его осаждает каламбуром (принижающим статус, мимоходом). Начальников/подчинённых в моём ответе можно просто вычеркнуть. Никакой разницы в употреблении позволить/разрешить в обоих цитатах искать не требуется (в первой нет, а во второй это просто параллельно).

Answer (score 0):

В общем я уже понял, что абсолютно правильного ответа тут не будет, да я и изначально понимал всю невозможность такого ответа коли вопрос больше напоминает опрос.

Моё понимание, пока - кратко, далее при необходимости разовью мысль.

Дозволять и позволять - ближайшие синонимы, говорить о различии значений не приходится. Разрешать - синоним близкий, но неполный.

При этом "дозволять" (и "позволять") хотя и употребляется сейчас реже, но имеет более широкую область возможного применения. Позволять можно что-то, во-первых пассивно, негласно закрывать на что-то глаза. Во-вторых, это модно делать как априорно, так и апостериорно - не зная подробностей и даже пост-фактум, то есть уже после совершения сомнительного действия.

Вот контекстные примеры на все три случая.
*Коту позволено валяться на хозяйской подушке.

Я могу себе позволить второй десерт после такого обеда.

Я не могу тебе позволить есть недозрелые яблоки из соседского сада.*
(Это годится даже для пойманного на мелкой краже сорванца, хотя он **уже** совершил действие).

"Разрешить" таких вольностей себе не позволяет. Тут все строго.
"Разрешите?" - "Разрешаю". Или не "разрешаю". Да, тут есть некая официальность, но она вроде как вторична. Первично то, что разрешение конкретно и безусловно дается **до** предполагаемого действия - и **активно дается**.

Ни в одном из трех предыдущих примеров, заменить "позволить" на "разрешить" просто так не удастся. Возникнет как минимум какая-то стилистическая неловкость. "Я могу себе разрешить пирожное"? - Так а кто запрещает, ma petite amie?! "Коту разрешено"? Ну это вряд ли. Ему именно **позволено**... Как-то так...

*Хотя, помнится, даже само слово "разрешение" (в этом значении) уже в советские времена вытеснило в русском общеславянское "дозволение". Что само по себе породило немало конфузов. Например, уже в эру компьютеров и далее - Интернета, понятие "(не)разрешенная ссылка" иногда трактовалось ошибочно как "(не)дозволенная", хотя там совершенно другой смысл, близкий к тому что реализуется в сочетании "разрешиться от бремени". Но это так, к слову.*

Чисто мое понимание. Без претензий на авторитетность мнения.

(+)
Вопрос о восприятии иностранцами ни мало для меня пока не прояснился.

Хотя, кажется, дошло.

В болгарском *позволяват* и *разрешеват* более или менее соответствует (в личных формах и без вопросов актива-пассива - там и там) английским *to be allowed* и *to permit*. А в русском эта граница смазана. Вот почему они и прочувствовали меня лучше, чем я сам.

Comment: По Вашим примерам с "позволено". Нашёл в словаре, что так обычно говорят о чём-то неправильном или таком, что обычно не делают. Судя по гугло-книгам, если речь идёт о чём-то привычном, то "разрешить себе", например, звучит вполне естественно. Вообще, рекомендую посмотреть "новый объяснительный словарь синонимов" Апресяна (есть на Либгене), если нет ощущения, что вопрос закрыт — там 5 страниц энциклопедического формата по этим трём синонимам.

Comment: @grizzly Хорошо, посмотрю, спасибо. Вопрос не закрыт, хотя с апресяном у меня роман не получился. ((( Как-то мы в разных реальностях существуем. Только скажите, как вы туда попадаете. Для меня либген - это вещь в себе...

Comment: По этой ссылке: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/ (в поисковой строке набрать Апресян). Дальше в колонке mirror выбирать зеркала, пока не попадётся работающее.

Comment: Ага, скачал уже. Сам разобрался, но спасибо.

Comment: @grizzly _Естественность_ выражения "разрешить себе" зависит от литературного контекста и возможна только в субъективном смысле, т. е. если персонаж - человек собранный и находится с самим собой в таких отношениях, что может себе что-то "**разрешить**" или даже "**приказать**", - это _не свойственно_ большинству людей. А "позволить себе" что-то может любой и всегда, даже не думая об этом, поэтому в общем случае (безотносительно личности) такая замена делает выражение излишне манерным со стороны литератора.

Answer (score 0):

Слово "позволять" хотя и употребляется сейчас реже, но имеет более широкую область возможного применения. Позволять можно что-то, во-первых, пассивно, негласно закрывать на что-то глаза. Во-вторых, это модно делать как априорно, так и апостериорно - не зная подробностей и даже пост-фактум, то есть уже после совершения сомнительного действия.